# How to write a regex expression to check a valid XML element NCName in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

NCNam  means that it must start with a letter or underscore, and can only contain letters, digits, underscores, hyphens, and periods.I have try to write the regex like this,but I think it may be wrong.

```
if(/^([_]|[a-zA-Z]+[\w\W])$/.test('abc' ))  console.log('match')
```

Comment: /^(_|[a-z])+(\w\d)/gi and add underscore and hypen and period to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `^([_]|[a-zA-Z]+[\w\W])$` pattern matches a string that is either equal to `_` (`[_]`) or (`|`) is formed of 1+ letters (`[a-zA-Z]+`) followed with any char (`[\w\W]`). So, it cannot validate the strings of the type you mention.

You may use

```
/^[a-zA-Z_][\w.-]*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tNxXtk/2) and the graph ([source](https://jex.im/regulex)) below:

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z_]` - a letter or  `_`
- `[\w.-]*` - 0 or more letters, digits, underscores, dots or hyphens
- `$` - end of string

Comment: FYI: To allow an empty string, wrap the consuming pattern part with an optional group, `/^(?:[a-zA-Z_][\w.-]*)?$/`. To require at least two chars, replace `*` (zero or more) with `+` (one or more): `/^[a-zA-Z_][\w.-]+$/`.

Answer (score 2):

> must start with a letter or underscore

Match the first character with `[a-z_]`

> and can only contain letters, digits, underscores, hyphens, and periods

Use a character class containing all of those. Note that letters, digits, and underscores together make up the representation of a "word character", so you can use `\w` instead of writing those out separately.

In full:

```
/^[a-z_][\w.-]*$/i
```